# How do I pipe the output of file to a variable in Python?

Tags: python

How do I pipe the output of file to a variable in Python?

Is it possible? Say to pipe the output of `netstat` to a variable x in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two parts:

Shell

```
netstat | python read_netstat.py
```

Python read_netstat.py

```
import sys
variable = sys.stdin.read()
```

That will read the output from netstat into a variable.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible. See:

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote

In Python 2.4 and above:

```
from subprocess import *
x = Popen(["netstat", "-x", "-y", "-z"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? I don't think the backticks call to the shell in Python and usage of them is discouraged anyway.

Comment: Hello, figured I'd try it.  The backticks are required at least using cygwin.  Without backticks I get help spit back at me.
>>> x = Popen(["netstat", "-a", "-b", "-e"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> x
'Interface Statistics\r\n\r\n                           Received            Sent\r\n\r\nBytes                     636096584        44729983\r\nUnicast
 packets              540296          297233\r\nNon-unicast packets         1058608             338\r\nDiscards                          0
   0\r\nErrors                            0              13\r\nUnknown protocols              4405\r\n'

Comment: Tried it in DOS also, same deal.  Back-ticks required.

Comment: @manifest: backticks in Python call repr on an object - they do not make calls to the shell.  When you say they are required, how are you using them?  They do not appear in the example you posted.

Comment: Sorry, the command with backticks is the shell command being replaced with a subprocess call. I've updated my answer. And I should have spotted that - we have loads of code that converts to strings with backticks! Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: I thought "back-ticks" referred to the "-" before each argument.  Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. It allows you to start new processes, interact with them, and read their output.

In particular see the section [Replacing /bin/sh shell backquote](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote):

```
output = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```